# Why my Mac OS X Startup Disk used space is around 30 GB

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I just bought a new MacBook Air 128GB SSD. This is my first MAC. As on Windows, I want to create a separate partition for my Data. The Default partition shows around 30 GB used space. Why is it so? I suppose Mavericks takes up around 10 GB only.

[image]

[image]

Secondly, what is the recommended size for Startup disk. I will only use it for development purpose - XCode, XAMP, Qt etc.

Comment: Have a look and see how much of the drive is already in use.  Apple symbol (top right) "about this Mac" the storage. How much is in use?

Comment: @Tetsujin Suppose i want to do a clean install of Mavericks or Yosemite, in that case it is required

Comment: It's not Windows, you don't need to clean install every 5 minutes. [edit] sorry, actually valid point if it's a dev machine.

Comment: @MichaelStoner It displays 98 GB free

Comment: Ok, if it's a new machine then I think that's a little high. I use a program (free) called GrandPerspective that allows you to see what files are taking up the space. Have a look and see why it's 30GB. It could be iphone back ups or local time machine backups.

Comment: @MichaelStoner I haven't added any data files yet, added a new screenshot, why apps and other data are consuming 20 GB

Comment: @adnankamili I think it's more like 15gb for Mavericks, but also does it come with iLife? GarageBand and iDVD? Use Grand Perspective to find out what's used the space. From another link some says it's about 106gb free left on a 128gb. Xcode takes 4-5GB btw the way and the simulators are 500-800MB each

Comment: It doesn't really answer your questions ( get http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/ for that), but I would suggest you rethink the partitioning since an SSD does not get much performance benifit (or any?) from partitioning like a spinning disk would, and the various wear-leveling stuff probably performs more effectively when operating across the whole drive. But maybe the wear-leveling stuff happens at a level below the partitioning scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you've got iLife for free, and installed which means you have:
Pages, Numbers, Keynote, iPhoto, GarageBand.
I suspect that this adds upto just under 5GB.
Delete them from the application folder if you don't need them.

This is the link to [grandperspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net), it's free and really great.

And as I said in the comments Xcode is big 3-5GB, the iOS Simulators are big.

If you are going to develop in the start-up partition, I would get your development environment set up now and then afterwards add the 2nd data partition in.

Oh and I forgot the **sleep image** - if you have **4GB RAM** then you'll have a sleep image **that mirrors the memory**.  If your Mac battery dies when you power it up it recovers the exact state it was in when it shut down. It's the same when it sleeps.  If you have 8GB then you'll have even less drive space.

Something to bear in mind when creating bootable partition.

This **can be turned off**, but not a great idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out what takes up space, I recommend using third party apps, either "Disk Inventory X" or "WhatSize".  Disk Inventory X is free, but quite old.  Alternatively you could just "Get Info" (command-i) on all your folders and add them up yourself.

As far as free space you'll need on your boot volume, assuming you won't be adding more applications to this volume, leave the same amount of space free as you have physical RAM installed in the machine.  If your going to be adding more apps to the machine, which is highly likely, increase size accordingly.